# Semigroups and solutions of equation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semigroups

It is easy to prove: in a finite semigroup if for all $a$ and $b$, $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ has unique solution. then it is group. But if in a finite semigroup, if for all $a$ and $b$, $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ has solution(not necessarily unique given) would it be a group?

Comment: So for fixed $a$ and variable $x$, the elements $ax$ would have to be all distinct in order to include every element $b$, so the solution would have to be unique., and it would be a group.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Thanks may I ask one more question here itself.    Can we find example of infinite group such that both above equation has solution but not unique

Comment: Maybe you mean to have each of $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ to have unique solutions $x$ and $y$ respectively. Because in the semigroup for which the multiplication $xy$ always returns $y$ the equation $ax=b$ reduces to $x=b$ (unique solution) and the same goes for $ay=b$.

Comment: Assuming that you meant $ya=b$, then I think even for an infinite semigroup, if solutions for all $a,b$, then it is a group.

Comment: Please give a correct version of your question, because $ax = b$ and $ay = b$ are just twice the same equation with a different name for the unknown. If you mean $by = a$, the answer is no and the minimal counterexample is the semigroup $S = \{a, b\}$ with the following multiplication table: $aa = ba = a$, $ab = bb = b$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short self-contained proof.

Suppose $S$ is a semigroup (finite or infinite, but of course nonempty) such that, for any $a,b\in S$, each of the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ has at least one solution in $S$. We will show that $S$ is a group. (In fact this is how groups are defined in some textbooks. If memory serves, this is how they are defined in a book by Kurosh.)

Choose elements $a\in S$ and $e\in S$ such that $ae=a$.

Consider any $x\in S$. Choose $y\in S$ so that $ya=x$. Then
$$xe=yae=ya=x.$$
Thus $e$ is a **right identity** element.

For any element $x\in S$ there is an element $x'\in S$ such that $xx'=e$, and an element $x''\in S$ such that $x'x''=e$. Then
$$x'x=x'xe=x'xx'x''=x'ex''=x'x''=e,$$
that is, $x'$ is a **two-sided inverse** of $x$ with respect to $e$.

Finally, for any $x\in S$ we have
$$ex=xx'x=xe=x,$$
so $e$ is a **two-sided identity** element. This completes the proof that $S$ is a group.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes and relies on the properties of [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) and Green's theorem, which states that if $H$ is an $\mathcal{H}$-class of a semigroup $S$, then either $H^2 \cap H = \emptyset$ or $H$ is a subgroup of $S$. In particular, the $\mathcal{H}$-class of an idempotent is a subgroup of S.

Let $S$ be a nonempty finite semigroup. Then $S$ contains an idempotent $e$. Now, for all $a \in S$, there exists a pair $(x,y) \in S^2$ such that $ax = e$ and $ya = e$ and another pair $(s,t) \in S^2$ such that $es = a$ and $te = a$. This implies that, for all $a \in S$, $e \mathrel{\mathcal{R}} a$ and $e \mathrel{\mathcal{L}} a$, whence $e \mathrel{\mathcal{H}} a$. Therefore, $S$ is equal to the $\mathcal{H}$-class of $e$, which is a group, as any $\mathcal{H}$-class containing an idempotent.

Comment: Is there a more elementary explanation? I follow up to $es = a$ and $te = a$.

Comment: The existence of an idempotent is proved at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup.

Comment: @6005 I have added references to Green's relations and stated Green's theorem. I am a bit reluctant to include a proof of Green's theorem, which is nontrivial but can be found in *any* book of semigroup theory.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I understand the proof now.

Comment: From Wikipedia it doesn't seem like Green's theorem requires the finiteness assumption. So is it true that: a semigroup S is a group iff (1) it has an idempotent, and (2) $ax = b$ and $ya = b$ have at least one solution for any $a,b$?