# If S is finite and $x/\rho$ is an idempotent of $S/\rho$ then $x/ \rho$ contains an idempotent

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, semigroups, congruence-relations

Currently working on the following problem, need a little help with the solution to the last part, any hints?

Q:
Let S be a semigroup, and let ρ be a congruence on S. Prove that if e ∈ S is an idempotent, then its
equivalence class e/ρ is a subsemigroup of S, and is an idempotent in the quotient S/ρ. Also, prove that if S is finite
and x/ρ is an idempotent of S/ρ then x/ρ contains an idempotent.

A:
e\ $\rho$ = $  x \in S : (e,x) \in \rho  $ ie the set of all things related to e.
This is a subset of S and thus still associative so to show it is a subsemigroup we just need to show closure which is easy using the fact $e^{2} = e$ and that the relation is a congruence.

Showing $e / \rho$  is an idempotent in the quotient $S / \rho$ is also fine by considering e/$\rho$ * e/ $\rho$ = $e^{2} / \rho$ = $e / \rho$ as e is an idempotent so thats dandy.

However the last line is the bit thats confusing me "prove that if S is finite and $x/\rho$ is an idempotent of $S/\rho$ then $x/ \rho$ contains an idempotent." Surely if $x/\rho$ is an idempotent, clearly $x/\rho$ $\in$ $x/\rho$? I dont really get what this is asking or why the finiteness condition is needed...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am a little confused by your notation, in particular when you write $x/{\rho} \in x/{\rho}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to state your question in terms of homomorphisms. Let $\rho: S \to T$ be a semigroup homomorphism. If $e$ is idempotent in $S$, then $\rho(e)$ is idempotent in $T$.
Furthermore, the set
$$
\{s \in S \mid \rho(s) = \rho(e) \}
$$
is equal to $\rho^{-1}(\rho(e))$ and hence is a subsemigroup of $S$. Finally if $\rho(x)$ is equal to an idempotent $f$ of $T$, then
$$
R = \{s \in S \mid \rho(s) = \rho(x) \} = \{s \in S \mid \rho(s) = f\} = \rho^{-1}(f)
$$
is a nonempty subsemigroup of $S$. If $S$ is finite, then so is $R$ and thus $R$ contains an idempotent.

Comment: Do you claim that any finite semigroup must have an idempotent element?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup