# Is it right to say: A finite semigroup always contains an idempotent element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, associativity

Is there a theorem which says: If an operation on a set is associative then the set contains idempotent?

Comment: "Contains idempotent" is never right to say. Which meaning are you trying to express with that combination of words?

Comment: Which other meaning there can be?

Comment: Other than _what_? Your words do not constitute a grammatical sentence.

Comment: What's the definition of idempotent? what other meaning there can be except the meaning of the definition?

Comment: I'm asking YOU what you mean by the nonsense words "the set contains idempotent". That is not an English sentence!

Comment: I mean the algebraic structure defined on the set with an operation contains an idempotent element

Comment: In that case, please edit your question such that it is in English.

Comment: I thought it would be clear.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Bbb N$ be the free semi-group on one generator.

Comment: i.e it isn't right for all finite sets?

Comment: @David: See [Is there an idempotent element in a finite semigroup?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup)