# Factoring a sufficiently long product in a finite semigroup such that certain subsequences yield the same element

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, semigroups, ramsey-theory

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup with $k$ elements. If we have at least $(nk)^k$ elements $s_1, \ldots, s_m$, i.e. $m \ge (nk)^k$, then the product
$$
 s_1 \cdot s_2 \cdots s_m 
$$
could be factored as $s_1 \cdot s_2 \cdots s_m = xy_1 y_2 \cdots y_n z$ (i.e. the elements $x,y_i,z$ combine a consecutive subsequence and equal their product) such that the product $y_i y_{i+1} y_{i+j}$ is the same for every permissible $i$ and $j$.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this? As $y_1 = \ldots = y_n$ and $y_i y_{i+1} = y_i$ the element must be an idempotent, but I do not know how to choose the factorisation/decomposition?

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to getting $s_1s_2\dots s_n=xw^nz$ with $w=w^2=\dots=w^n$ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Yes, you are right.

Comment: This is probably going to be a combination of induction and the pidgeon-hole principle.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I know this result that in a finite semigroup every element has an idempotent power, in particular $S$ contains at least one idempotent. But its application seems to be more tricky here...

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that one of the consecutive subproducts is an idempotent? I don't see what the point of $n$ is.

Comment: The $y_i$ "combine the elements" from the sequence, i.e. we have $y_1 = s_{k_1}\cdots s_{k_2-1}, y_2 = s_{k_2}\cdots s_{k_3-1}$ and so on for some subsequence $(k_i)$, i.e. the $n$ says that we can group the elements in such a way, so in that sense your first comment is a little bit weaker and not equivalent which I noticed yet. If we can group the product in such a way what you wrote in your first comment would follow, but if this condition holds it it not said that we can group certain consecutive $s_i$'s as to give $n$ times $w$ from your comment.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see your point.

Comment: :) it does not seem to be that straightforward, at least I do not see how to use induction and the pigeon-hole principle. Surely it is related to these principles, but I guess they must be applied in some very clever way...