# Semigroup homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

Let $S$ and $T$ are monoids. Prove or disprove if $\varphi: S \to T$ is a Semigroup homomorphism, then $ \varphi$ is monoid homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there is an idempotent element $e$ in the monoid $T$ and $\phi:S\rightarrow T:x\mapsto e$, then $\phi$ is a semi group homomorphism, but the unit element of $S$ is mapped to $e$ and $e$ may not be the unit element of $T$.

About idempotents in semigroups see [Is there an idempotent element in a finite semigroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup)

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: It might be useful for some readers to mention the smallest specific example of what is described in this answer: Let $S=\{0\}$ and $T=\{0,1\}$, both with ordinary multiplication as the operation, and let $\varphi$ send $0$ to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the zero map $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $a \mapsto 0$, where we consider $\mathbb{Z} = (\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$ as a monoid. This is obviously a homomorphism of semigroups as $f(ab) = 0 = 0 \cdot 0 = f(a)f(b)$, but will not send the multiplicative identity $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to itself and thus is not a homomorphism of monoids.