# Existence of a matrix such that $A^2+A=0$ among a finite set of matrices stable for a certain operation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $n > 0$ is fixed, and suppose $S$ is a finite collection of $n × n$ matrices with the
following property:

> if $A, B ∈ S$, then (1) $AB + A + B ∈ S$.
>
> Show that there exists a matrix
> $A ∈ S$ such that (2)  $A^2 + A = 0$.

My first attempt was BWOC
so if (2) is false for all $A$ in $S$ then (1) is false since there would be an A in S with (1) not holding , but I'm struggling with showing it with using products of matrices ..as in $BXA$
..maybe bwoc is the wrong attack ?

Comment: Please don't make an abusive use of acronyms ; I have been obliged to look in a dictionnary for  BWOC = By Way Of Contradiction.  Think to all people who are not fluent in English...

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title "Showing a powerful result in Linear Algebra" which did not convey the content of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Define the binary operation $\odot$ on $S$:
$$A \odot B = AB + A + B = (A + I)(B + I) - I.$$
This operation is associative, making it a finite semigroup. Now use the fact that [every finite semigroup has an idempotent element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353028/is-there-an-idempotent-element-in-a-finite-semigroup/353042) to conclude the existence of some $A \in S$ such that
$$A \odot A = A \implies A^2 + 2A = A \implies A^2 + A = 0.$$

Comment: It’s a finite collection of matrices

Comment: Good point @Amit. Unfortunately, I can't delete my answer.

Comment: I liked your answer until I noticed that. Good try!

Comment: What you are saying is:
$$T:=\{ A+ I: A \in S \}$$
Then, if $C,D \in T$ we have $CD \in T$.

Comment: Looks good to me now

Comment: It is to be noted that we have realized a structure transfer by writing the definition of $\odot$ in this way $t(A \odot B) = t(A) . t(B)$ with $t(A)=A+I$.