# Finite monoids are groups

Tags: monoid

Are all finite monoids groups?

If I have a monoid $M$ such that $|M|=c$ for an integer $c$, then for all $x\in M$, we should have $x^k=e$ for some minimal $k$. Then, we have $x^{-1}=x^{k-1}$.

I don't see anything wrong with my proof, but I haven't found an answer online, and it doesn't feel like a `trivial' result, so I'm wondering if this is true.

Comment: It's definitely **not** true: consider the monoid with underlying set $\{0,1\}$ and operation $\max$ (so that $0$ is the identity and $1$ is an annihilator). Using this example, do you see where your argument breaks down?

Comment: I see. I can have $x^n=x$ for some $n$, but I can't extend this argument to $x^m=e$ for $m=n-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You argument is definitely wrong, but it can be modified to get a property related to groups. Take an element $x$ of a finite monoid $M$. First show that $x$ has an idempotent power, that is, for some $k > 0$, $x^k = x^{2k}$
(or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4125208) for a proof). Next show that there is a maximal subsemigroup of $M$ which is a group with $x^k$ as identity.